# captureVideo Cordova Phonegap app stops recording at 10 minutes

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I have built a mobile app for iOS and Android using Phonegap / Cordova.

Using the media-capture plugin my app on iOS will only record videos up to 10 minutes (there is plenty of space on my phone ).

Is there a way to increase this to a longer duration or is this a setting I can not control with the plugin but maybe I can change in xCode?

I've tried changing the options:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, quality: 1, duration: 3600});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes is the maximum time allowed by the component the plugin uses

> Discussion
>
> The system-enforced maximum duration for a video recording is 10 minutes; you can set this value to 10 minutes or less. The default value for this property is also 10 minutes.
> The video editor user interface forces the user to trim a loaded movie to fit within this property’s value prior to saving.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivideoeditorcontroller/1622338-videomaximumduration